# Is this function Hölder continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x)=x^\alpha \int_x^1 y^{-\alpha-1}(y-x)^{-\alpha}dy, \quad x\in [0,1],$$
where $\alpha\in (0,1/2)$ is some fixed parameter.

Is $f$ Hölder continuous of any order? Somehow I have the feeling it is since it is an integral but theoretically this is not enough.

Any ideas on how to prove or disprove it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable $y=t\,x$ gives
$$
f(x)=x^{-\alpha}\int_1^{1/x}t^{-\alpha-1}(t-1)^{-\alpha}\,dt.
$$
As $x\to1$, $f$ behaves like $x^{-\alpha}$. We see that $f$ is$C^1$ on $(0,1]$, but is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: What a pity! I am trying to find bounds of the type $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C |x-y|^{\beta}$, of course it is not possible but maybe with $\beta<0$ or something like $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C h(x,y)$ for some function $h$ which is integrable on $[0,1]^2$.